# Issues with the response from the server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I implemented a calculator with AJAX, PHP and JavaScript. Calculation is done in the PHP code. When I send the server the request for the response, I am getting the whole source code of the PHP file. How can I prevent this?

This is my JavaScript code:

```
 var xmlHTTP;
    var operation;

    function process() {


        var number1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;

        var num1 = parseInt(number1);

        var number2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;
        var num2 = parseInt(number2);


        var answer;
        if (document.getElementById('+').checked) {
            operation='add';
        } else if (document.getElementById('-').checked) {
            operation='subs';
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('*').checked) {
            operation='mul';
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('/').checked) {
            operation='div';
        }

    }
    function loadDoc() {
        process();
        xmlHTTP=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = function () {
            alert(xmlHTTP.readyState);
            alert(xmlHTTP.status);
            if (xmlHTTP.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

                document.getElementById("cal").i=xmlHTTP.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlHTTP.open("POST","process.php?value1=num1&value2=num2&value3=operation", true);
        xmlHTTP.send();

    }


  <?php

$number1 = $_POST['value1'];
$number2=$_POST['value2'];
$answer=0;
$op=$_POST['operation'];

//echo $answer;
if($op="add"){
    $answer=$number1+$number2;
}
elseif($op="subs"){
    $answer=$number1-$number2;
}
elseif($op="mul"){
    $answer=$number1*$number2;
}
elseif($op="div"){
    $answer=$number1/$number2;
}
else{
    echo "Choose an operation";
}
echo $answer;
```

Comment: can you show a snippet of the code you're using?

Comment: Are you running it on a PHP-enabled server? Something like apache?

Comment: I suggest you to use two separate files.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the entire code being sent back to the ajax function, in the php script that does the caluclations try something like:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
    ob_clean(); /* discard any output there might have been to this point */

    /* do the calculations */

    /* send response */
    echo $answer;

    exit();
}
```

late update
having now seen the additional code you posted I can see some minor mistakes with the php - you are using a single `=` to test if a value equals something, that is incorrect as it is used to set the value. You need to use a double `==` to test for equality or `===` for strict equality tests.
So, in conjunction with what I suggested before perhaps something akin to this:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();
        $number1 = $_POST['value1'];
        $number2 = $_POST['value2'];
        $answer=0;
        $op=$_POST['operation'];


        if($op=="add"){
            $answer=$number1+$number2;
        } elseif($op=="subs"){
            $answer=$number1-$number2;
        } elseif($op=="mul"){
            $answer=$number1*$number2;
        } elseif($op=="div"){
            $answer=$number1/$number2;
        } else{
            echo "Choose an operation";
        }
        if( $answer ) echo $answer;
        exit();
    }
?>
```

I took a closer look at the javascript code you posted and found a couple of issues which certainly wouldn't help - hopefully the following might help.

```
/* The values calculated inside this function would not necessarily have been available to 
   the ajax function so this function returns them as an object. */

function process() {
    var operation;
    var number1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
    var num1 = parseInt(number1);

    var number2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;
    var num2 = parseInt(number2);

    var answer;
    /* Are these valid IDs for DOM elements??? */
    if( document.getElementById('+').checked ) operation='add';
    else if( document.getElementById('-').checked ) operation='subs';
    else if( document.getElementById('*').checked ) operation='mul';
    else if( document.getElementById('/').checked ) operation='div';

    return {
        n1:num1,
        n2:num2,
        op:operation    
    }
}

/* You never actually sent the values from the `process` function as they
   were not properly escaped/unquoted. */

function loadDoc() {
    var obj=process();
    var xmlHTTP=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHTTP.readyState == 4 && xmlHTTP.status == 200 ) {
            document.getElementById("cal").innerHTML=xmlHTTP.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHTTP.open( "POST", "process.php?value1="+obj.n1+"&value2="+obj.n2+"&value3="+obj.op, true );
    xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlHTTP.send();
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same response :(

Comment: By the way why did use this code snippet "  if( $answer ) echo $answer; "

Comment: initially you set `$answer=0;` and zero equates to false so I just used that `if($answer)echo $answer;` to only echo if not zero / false

Comment: Thanks i finnaly figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

After `echo $answer;` use  `exit();` or `die();`. 
The AJAX request sent to the page will returns the entire page source as response if the script is not stopped using `exit();`, and their should not be any other echo before your `echo $answer;` because it will also be added along with your response.
Instead of using multiple if and elseif statement you can use the switch case.

Eg:

```
...
Switch($op) {
    case 'add':
      $answer=$number1+$number2;
      break;
     ...
     ...

}


echo $answer;
die();
```

Comment: i used it but still the same thing is happening

Comment: Thanks i finnaly figured it out :)